# jQuery append option in select dropdown from json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

```
$.getJSON('js/countries.json', function (data) {
            $.each(data, function (i=0,name,code) {
                // console.log(data[i]['name'] + '=' + data[i]['code']);
                $('#ppState').append($('<option>', {
                    value: data[i]['code'],
                    text: data[i]['name']
                }));
            });
        });
```

Can anybody tell why this code is not working?
It does not append any options in my select html output.
Console works just fine.

HTML code:

```
<select id="ppState" name="ppState">
    <option value="">Choose Country</option>
</select>
```

JSON file:

```
[
  {
    "name": "Afghanistan",
    "code": "AF"
  },
  {
    "name": "Åland Islands",
    "code": "AX"
  },
  {
    "name": "Albania",
    "code": "AL"
  }

]
enter code here
```

**EDIT:**

It appending options in the first select element that jQuery selector finds.
However I have several same select element in the html. How to target them all?

Comment: Have you double-checked the `ppState` element ID? Any errors in the console? (Why `i=0` as the first function argument? You shouldn't need to provide a default for a `$.each()` callback argument.)

Comment: Try concat strings and append plain html. You are trying to append a jquery object. Maybe it works but plain html always works.

Comment: Double checked ppState. no errors in the console.

Comment: Your `$.each()` seems to work fine here: https://jsfiddle.net/rt6cqw0x/

Answer (score 0):

Your jQuery each function and the formatting of your appear option is not correct.

```
// yours.......
$.each(data, function (i=0,name,code) {
                // console.log(data[i]['name'] + '=' + data[i]['code']);
                $('#ppState').append($('<option>', {
                    value: data[i]['code'],
                    text: data[i]['name']
                }));
            });


// should
$.each(data, function (item) {
    var opt = $('<option></option>');

    opt.val(item.code);
    opt.text(item.name);

    $('#ppState').append($(opt);
  });
```

### Update

```
$.each(data, function (item) {
    $('#ppState').append($('<option value="' +item.code+ '">' +item.name+ '</option>'));
  });
```

Comment: The OP's `$.each()` works as is: https://jsfiddle.net/rt6cqw0x/ - assuming you use a browser that doesn't mind the ES6 default parameter `i=0` (that default is pointless, but valid ES6 syntax). As for passing an object as the second argument of `$('<option>', {...})`, that's perfectly valid jQuery.

Comment: It is working in the first select. However, I have several same select element in the html. Any idea how to append to all of them?

Answer (score 0):

Your code works well for me.

I had wrong characters for the Åland Islands in the dropdown list, so I had to re-save the JSON file, changing from ANSI to UTF-8.

Answer (score 0):

> *It appending options in the first select element that jQuery selector finds. However I have several same select element in the html. How to target them all?*

If you've reused the same `id` attribute then your HTML is invalid, and jQuery will find only the first (as you've seen).

It *is* valid to give multiple elements the same `name` attribute, so if your elements all have `name="ppState"` then you can select by that:

```
$('select[name="ppState"]').append(...
```

Or you can add a common class to each element:

```
<select id="ppState" name="ppState" class="state">

$('select.state').append(...
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help you to append

these code i used in spring boot MVC

JSON Data

```
[{"name":"Afghanistan","code":"af"},
{"name":"Albania","code":"al"},
{"name":"Algeria","code":"dz"}]
```

JQuery Code

```
var jsonData = '${restData}';
var obj = JSON.parse(jsonData);
for (i in obj) {
    $('#selectList').append(new Option(obj[i].name, obj[i].code));

}
```